# How set Animation's option in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, uiviewanimation

When i set animation's options in swift4, displayed error.
How can i set curve options.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {})
```

```
Argument 'animations' must precede argument 'options'
Replace 'options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {

    }' with 'animations: {

    }, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut'
```

Comment: the error actually tells you how to fix it. `UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, , animations: {}, options: .curveEaseInOut)`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.
The problem is that I have to make sure to set "delay" to set the option.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this method with the animation option `.curveEaseInOut`.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {

}) { (isCompleted) in

}
```